# evaluate $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac {i^c}{2^i}$

Tags: summation

I want to evaluate the sum : $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac {i^c}{2^i}$ , when c is some positive constant also could you show the way to compute it ? could any one provide way to compute it when c=1 or other value if could not compute the original one !

Comment: The way to compute it is to compute the $n+1$ terms in the sum and add them up. For most $c$, you can't do much better than that, if you want the exact value. For small positive integer values of $c$, it can be done, and has been done on this website, several times (though it's not so easy to find past instances).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find the previous answer.   for small natural $c$, we have $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac 1{x^i}=\frac {1-x^{-(n+1)}}{1-\frac 1x}$.  Then for $c=1$, $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac i{x^i}=\sum_{i=0}^n- x \frac d{dx}\frac  1{x^i}=- x \frac d{dx}\frac {1-x^{-(n+1)}}{1-x}$, now evaluate it at $x=2$.  For larger $c$, repeat the process, applying the operator $-x \frac d{dx} c$ times to each side.  I love taking the derivative with respect to $2$.

Comment: thank you this exactly what I was looking for ... but the first sum is not correct it should be $\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x^n(x-1)}$

Comment: You're right.  I was thinking of the sum of $x$, not $\frac 1x$.  Fixed.

Comment: this works exactly like mathematics ...

Comment: what this method called ?